# Angular 9 - Event Emitter does not emit

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I am trying to pass data from a form-component to modal-component using Event Emitter. Below is how how I have configured it -

Form.ts

```
@Output() userEmail = new EventEmitter;

submit(order): void {
this.userEmail.emit(order.value.email);
console.log('1', order.value.email);
this.orderForm.postOrderForm(order.value);
this.openOrderFormModal();
}
```

Form-modal.html

```
<div id="order-form-modal">
    <h3>{{ 'order.form.notify.heading.1' | translate }} </h3>
    <p> {{ 'order.form.notify.msg.1' | translate }}</p>
    <p> {{ 'order.form.notify.msg.2' | translate }}</p>
    <p (userEmail)="setEmail($event)">{{email}}</p>
    <button (click)="closeOrderFormModal()" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Close</button>
</div>
```

Form Modal.ts

```
email;
setEmail(userEmail:string) {
this.email=userEmail
console.log(userEmail)
}
```

Below is the output I get:

[image]
My Form Module is As follows - 
Form (Folder)
    Form.html
    Form.ts
         Form-Modal (Folder)
         Form-Modal.html
         Form-Modal.ts
Please assist. If you need more info, please let me know.

Thank you!
Aditya Prakash

Comment: `EventEmitter` is generic AFIK. Double check you're importing it from `@angular/core`

Comment: Thanks for the response @dcg, below is my import statement in form.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it wrong -

```
<p (userEmail)="setEmail($event)">{{email}}</p>
```

You cannot use a custom EventEmitter created on a component as a directive on an HTML element.

The usage is, consider parent and child component -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: ` ... some template .....   `
})
class ChildComponent {

  @Output() userEmail = new EventEmitter();         <-------------- Also, EventEmitter is a class. You need to create an instance of it

  submit(order): void {
      this.userEmail.emit(order.value.email);
   }
}
```

You can listen in parent component to the userEmail event as -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: ` <app-child (userEmail)="emailChanged($event)"></app-child>  `
})
class ParentComponent {
  emailChanged(userEmail:string) {
    console.log(userEmail)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vimal, Thanks for the response. I modified my code to - 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-form-modal',
  template: `<app-order-form (userEmail)="setEmail($event)">{{email}}</app-order-form>`,
  styleUrls: ['./order-form-modal.component.css']
})

Still no output. Can you let me know if the changes are accurate?

Comment: Can you please share the full code of updated components?

Comment: `import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-form-modal',
  template: `<app-order-form (userEmail)="setEmail($event)">{{email}}</app-order-form>`,
  styleUrls: ['./order-form-modal.component.css']
})
export class OrderFormModalComponent {
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OrderFormModalComponent>) { }
  email;
  setEmail(userEmail:string) {
    this.email=userEmail
    console.log(userEmail)
  }

  closeOrderFormModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
`

Comment: <app-order-form (userEmail)="setEmail($event)"></app-order-form> without {{email}}
you put {{email}} in the template/html file of the child component.